# Do something before onCreate()?

Tags: android

Is there a way to do some stuff before `onCreate()` of the MainActivity is called?

We want to do some initializing stuff like logging...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html read

Comment: OnCreate is about to initialize stuff ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options;

1 . If your logging is not related to the activity about to start, rather, you'd need 'some' initialisation before the first activity starts then subclass `android.app.Application`. The `onCreate` method here is pretty much the first thing to run when your application starts.

For example, in our app this is where we create our DI injector's or decide whether the app needs a database created ("Preparing for first use") type tasks.

This seems like a good fit for application wide logging subsystem initialisation...

2 . Failing that (and if you want to log precisely just before an Activity's `onCreate` method is called) then this is a classic use-case for Aspects. We use AspectJ for similar reasons alongside database transaction management. Refer to [this blog entry](http://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2011/07/18/aspect-oriented-android-development-tool-integration/) on how to weave the code you require in the Android build system.

Answer (score 4):

First you create an activity for loging purpose.And set this as your launcher activity.Then start your main activity from this activity after login completes.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This should be added to the manifest to mark an actvity as launcher activity

Answer (score 3):

If you refer to Activity life cycle, I doubt it is possible.
[image]

But you can create a service or another activity which are launched prior it.
Do your logging in the background and pass the information your main activity!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [static initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to your Activity. It will be run exactly once per process, the first time this Activity is invoked and before any other Activity method is run.

If your initialization code is not related to this Activity but to the whole app, the best approach is usually to create a lazily initialized singleton class, or in some cases it may be acceptable to add the initialization code to `Application.onCreate()` by overriding this method after subclassing `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another Activity and set that as launcher. And do your stuff in that activity. And on completion of your task, start main activity.