# I can not access the location of android device in onCreate() function

Tags: android, location

I'm developing an android application which is supposed to get the location of the android device when the activity is created `(onCreate)`. But it returns 0 longitude and 0 latitude when activity is created. When I click the button, the location is then fetched.

How can I get the location when the activity starts, instead of getting the location after clicking on the button?

-All permissions are granted

-I'm calling the same functions in `onCreate()` and `onClick()` to get the location.

-I'm using googleAPI to get the location of the device

Comment: What you are trying to achieve maybe will work with LastKnownLocation that you will get from LocationManager. Location is not something instant, you should register to location listener and get the location in the Callback. Do not expect it synchronously

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981238/do-something-before-oncreate

Answer (score 1):

**try using the function in onStart() or onResume(), it can work**

Comment: I have tried it, but It does not show the location unless I minimize my application and then open it again.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
            LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
}
```

and to get the location and update the UI, use onLocationChanged

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        //your code here (update UI, etc.)
    }
};
```